# sbt test - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, sbt, java.library.path

I have a scala app that I build with sbt.
It pulls in a native library.
The native library is loaded via...

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "libs")
System.loadLibrary("native-library")
```

The app runs absolutely fine on both Ubuntu 14 and 16.
I can execute sbt test and run no problem and it all links up perfectly.

I am testing out building on Ubuntu 18 and am running into issues.
They seem to be specifically related to loading/linking the native library.
The app runs fine if I use "sbt run".
However if I try "sbt test" it fails with the following error...

```
sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class "MyClass"
```

where "MyClass" is the class that links the native library.
The app also compiles fine (sbt compile) and I have included "fork := true" in my build.sbt.

So I know it "works" in some scenarios. There just seems to be something specific about "sbt test" where it breaks.

Thanks!